# Reduce Font Size by 1 Step in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, font-size

Is there a simple way to reduce the Font Size in Word / Excel etc by 1 step in VBA?

So, say if my Font size was 48 could I reduce it to 36, easily, as per the Font drop down in the standard Word 2007 Font group, rather than reducing the font size by 12 - I will not know what the next font size down is...

So rather than setting Font Size explicitly by float :

```
MyText.Font.Size = 36;
```

could I do something like :

```
MyText.Font.Size -= Reduce by 1 step;....  forgive the pseudo code!
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why is it so important to get the same font sizes as those listed in the drop down?

Comment: Hmph, clients. Allow me to rephrase: Why does the client want to do this?

Comment: I'm adding a Text Box to a powerpoint slide programmatically - they want the Font Size to be 2 'Steps' lower than the Slide Title.. I didn't mention Powerpoint in my original question as I naively thought I could transfer the Word / Excel code to Powerpoint - the Shrink method is exactly what I need, shame its not in Powerpoint :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Excel, you can check the Font Size combobox on the Formatting toolbar.  That's 2003 stuff and I think it will still work in 2007 and beyond, but I don't have it available to test.

```
Sub FontShrink(rng As Range)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim ctl As CommandBarComboBox

    Set ctl = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").Controls("Font Size:")

    If rng.Font.Size > CDbl(ctl.List(ctl.ListCount)) Then
        'if it's bigger than the biggest, make it the biggest
        rng.Font.Size = ctl.List(ctl.ListCount)
    Else
        For i = ctl.ListCount To 2 Step -1
            If rng.Font.Size > CDbl(ctl.List(i)) Then
                rng.Font.Size = CDbl(ctl.List(i))
                Exit For
            ElseIf rng.Font.Size = CDbl(ctl.List(i)) Then
                rng.Font.Size = CDbl(ctl.List(i - 1))
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant! +1  Note that this won't work if the initial font size isn't part of the list, e.g. if it's 17. Change to `If ctl.List(i) >= rng.Font.Size Then` to handle such cases.

Comment: Good one JFC. Edited code to take it down to the next level when it's in between.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Font`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221471%28v=office.11%29.aspx) object's [`Shrink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220897%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method:

```
MyText.Font.Shrink
```

The opposite is `MyText.Font.Grow`.

Comment: Thanks Jean-François, please see my comments above, Joe

Comment: Unfortunately, some brilliant developer at Microsoft decided that `Font.Shrink` and `Font.Grow` should only be available in Word and not in PowerPoint or Excel. I'm afraid you're stuck decrementing your font size in arbitrary steps, e.g. `MyText.Font.Size = MyText.Font.Size - 2`. Not that the font sizes listed in the drop down are any less arbitrary...

Comment: Sure Ok, do you know any way I can get to font size list.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

You can [Grow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172300%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [Shrink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220897%28v=office.11%29.aspx) fonts.

Comment: Thanks Anders, This is exactly what I need. I also need to do it in Powerpoint 2007 however - and the Shrink method is not available on a Text box shape, so 'myTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size.Shrink' is not available - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251433(v=office.12).aspx - any ideas? Thanks very much, Joe